# Show and hide div on clicking image or radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I have multiple images and their respective radio button. By clicking on an image or radio button their respective show and hide div is displaying.

But I am not able to achieve:

1. By clicking on the image the respective radio button should also select (have value true) when the text is showing
2. When the text is hiding then the radio button should have value false.

I have code so far as below:

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)">Flower 1</p>
<div id="Div_1" style="display: none;">
  Flower is pink.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_2)" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" onclick="Show_Div(Div_2)">Flower 2</p>
<div id="Div_2" style="display: none;">
  Flower is orange.
</div>
```

#### JavaScript code

```
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
  if (false == $(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
    $(Div_id).show(250);
  } else {
    $(Div_id).hide(250);
  }
}
```

Comment: `$(':radio').on('change', function() { $(':radio:checked').next('div').show(); });`

Comment: @ Tushar: above line, should I keep in JS part? I tried same but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio is the child of the previous adjacent element.

```
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
  if (!$(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', true);
    $(Div_id).show(250);
  } else {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', false);
    $(Div_id).hide(250);
  }
}
```

1. `.prev()` selects the `<p>` element that comes before the image
2. `.children()` selects the child element (ie the radio button in this case)

If you add additional elements to `<p>` you'll likely need to add additional selectors (ex first(), filter()) to drill down to the input element.

**The advantage of this approach is...**

You don't have to add any additional #id tags to your code. So, if you plan to repeat this pattern you'll have one less detail to worry about.

Comment: @ Evan Plaice: how I can set that only one radio button value true at one time among multiple radio buttons? Can you please add that in your answer?

Comment: @kiran I think you add  `.find("[value='value of radio button being changed']")` between `.children()` and `.prop()`

Comment: @ Evan Plaice: for above my HTML code, for group of two, how can I add that so that only one radio button should show text at a time?

Comment: @kiran That's not the question you asked here. With that said, you'd need to tie the two elements together. If you ask it in a new question, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pass id as a string rather than as HTML object, 
Use id's for radio buttons to set/unset their values.
To set single radio button at once and show the corresponding div with it, add class for both div's and radio buttons, hide the div and set radio's to false at the first line of Show_Div function.

```css
body {
    padding: 5px;
}

label {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20em
}

p {
    margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" id="Radio_Div_1" class="radio_btns" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')">&nbsp;Flower 1</p>
<div id="Div_1" class="divs" style="display: none;"><br>
  Flower is pink.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" id="Radio_Div_2" class="radio_btns" onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')">&nbsp;Flower 2</p>
<div id="Div_2" class="divs" style="display: none;"><br>
  Flower is orange.
</div>
</body>
<script>
 function Show_Div(Div_id) {
      $(".radio_btns").prop( "checked", false );
    $(".divs").hide(250);
   if (!$("#"+Div_id).is(':visible')) {
     $("#"+Div_id).show(250);
     $( "#Radio_"+Div_id).prop( "checked", true );
   } else {
     $("#"+Div_id).hide(250);
     $( "#Radio_"+Div_id).prop( "checked", false );
   }
 }

</script>
```

Comment: I have edited your answer since the first revision would quality as 'Not an Answer'. Posting only a link to an external site as an answer is not considered useful, so please keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @Geethanjali B L : how I can set that only one radio button value true at one time among multiple radio buttons? Can you please add that in your answer?

Comment: Add class="radio_btns" to all radio buttons in HTML, at the beginning of Show_Div() function set all radio to false by $( ".radio_btns").prop( "checked", false );   , then you can set/unset radio btn you clicked by its Id.

Answer (score 0):

Add a single quote to when passing a string to a function. You can try like:

#### HTML

```
 <input type="radio" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')">Flower 1</p>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
    $('#'+Div_id).toggle(250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<script>
    function Show_Div(Div_id) {
        var divid = "#" + Div_id;
        var inpcls = "." + Div_id;
        if (false == $(divid).is(':visible')) {
            $(divid).show(250);
            $(inpcls).prop("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $(divid).hide(250);
            $(inpcls).prop("checked", false);
        }
    }
</script>

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" class='Div_1' onclick="Show_Div('Div_1')">Flower 1</p>
<div id="Div_1" style="display: none;">
    Flower is pink.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')" width="100px">
<p>
    <input type="radio" class='Div_2' onclick="Show_Div('Div_2')">Flower 2</p>
<div id="Div_2" style="display: none;">
    Flower is orange.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the div Id by assigning the Id as title for the curresponding radio, and use toggle.

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
   $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop("checked", true);
   $('input[type="radio"]').change();
});
$('input[name="group"]').change(function() {
  var divId = $(this).attr('title');
  $('#'+divId).toggle($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Here is the [Code](http://codepen.io/nimmyks/pen/meqgBN)