# select one radio button from group with the show hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, radio-group

I am extending my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212204/show-and-hide-div-on-clicking-image-or-radio-button?noredirect=1#comment54228406_33212204). I am trying now if one of the radio button is selected then other should de-select by default.

I have tried by adding this :

**JS**

```
function Show_Div(Div_id) {
  if (!$(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', true);
    $(Div_id).show(250);
  } else {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', false);
    $(Div_id).hide(250);
  }
}
    function cbChange1(obj) {
        var cb1 = document.getElementsByClassName("cb1");
        for (var i = 0; i < cb1.length; i++) {
            cb1[i].checked = false;
        }
        obj.checked = true;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)" width="100px">
    <p>
      <input type="radio" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)" class="cb1" onchange="cbChange1(this)">Flower 1</p>
    <div id="Div_1" style="display: none;">
      Flower is pink.
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_2)" width="100px">
    <p>
      <input type="radio" onclick="Show_Div(Div_2)" class="cb1" onchange="cbChange1(this)">Flower 2</p>
    <div id="Div_2" style="display: none;">
      Flower is orange.
    </div>
```

But by above code only the radio buttons are select and de-select. The show and hide div which is connected with radio buttons is not show and hide by above.

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: replace from `Show_Div(Div_2)` to `Show_Div('#Div_2')`

Comment: If you can click it, it means you can see it, `.is(':visible')` should always return `true`. So is there any point in testing what you already know to be true? I am definitely missing something here!! ... And it should be `'#Div_2'` ... although I am not a fan of inline JS.

Comment: By design, when several radio buttons have the same value for the `name` attribute, only one can be selected at a time. Select one deselects any that was previously selected. .. Are we trying to re-invent the wheel here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about it wrong, it's actually quite simple.  If two radio boxes are effectively *answers* to the same question then all you need to do is give both elements the same `name`.  Then to handle showing and hiding of `div`'s you can do this -

```js
function Show_Div(Div_id, element) {
  $("input[name='radio1']").not(element).parent().next('div').hide(250);
  if (!$(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', true);
    $(Div_id).show(250);
  } else {
    $(Div_id).prev().children().prop('checked', false);
    $(Div_id).hide(250);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/flower-icon.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_1)" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="Show_Div('#Div_1')" class="cb1" >Flower 1</p>
<div id="Div_1" style="display: none;">
  Flower is pink.
</div>
<br/>
<br/>

<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/d/w/v/V/p/pink-flower-md.png" alt="" onclick="Show_Div(Div_2)" width="100px">
<p>
  <input type="radio" name="radio1" onclick="Show_Div('#Div_2')" class="cb1" >Flower 2</p>
<div id="Div_2" style="display: none;">
  Flower is orange.
</div>
```

Comment: @ John C : its not working well with my show and hide div code.

Comment: Hi @kiran check out my updated answer with show/hide functionality

Comment: @ John C: please check my previous question. link is in my above question. I had show and hide functionality for both image and radio button. Now with that solution I want above question functionality also.

Comment: @kiran Something like this?